# How to setup Symfony5 on IIS (wwwroot)

Tags: iis, symfony5

I tried alot to setup my symfony5 on IIS.
I know i need a web.config file. But i dont know which folders i need to place it in and which content it should have.

Is there someone who can help me ?

This is my folder structure:

https://prnt.sc/7JYFDefYmrRM

i tried a web.config file in my wwwroot with this content

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration>
    <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" 
           ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="app.php" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
           </rules>
         </rewrite>
   </system.webServer>
   </configuration>
```

When i get the 404 error it said C:\inetpub\wwwroot\bbmolenzicht\public\sfeer

But my files are in the templates folder.
When i run the command php bin/console debug router i get this:
https://prnt.sc/1SXuXo7DCUP4

How can i fix this?

Comment: You should put it in `Public` folder and put the application under it. The make IIS site path points to `Public` folder.

Comment: I did. now i cant go my templates. if i go to localhost/sfeer i got: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\bbmolenzicht\public\sfeer

But my /sfeer page it from a controller which render templates/sfeer/index.html.twig